# What's the most idiomatic way of working with an Iterator of Results?

Tags: rust, iterator, map-function, filterfunction, rust-result

I have code like this:

```
let things = vec![/* ...*/]; // e.g. Vec<String>
things
    .map(|thing| {
        let a = try!(do_stuff(thing));
        Ok(other_stuff(a))
    })
    .filter(|thing_result| match *thing_result {
        Err(e) => true,
        Ok(a) => check(a),
    })
    .map(|thing_result| {
        let a = try!(thing_result);
        // do stuff
        b
    })
    .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
```

In terms of semantics, I want to stop processing after the first error.

The above code works, but it feels quite cumbersome. Is there a better way? I've looked through the docs for something like `filter_if_ok`, but I haven't found anything.

I am aware of `collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>`, and it works great. I'm specifically trying to eliminate the following boilerplate:

- In the filter's closure, I have to use `match` on `thing_result`. I feel like this should just be a one-liner, e.g. `.filter_if_ok(|thing| check(a))`.
- Every time I use `map`, I have to include an extra statement `let a = try!(thing_result);` in order to deal with the possibility of an `Err`. Again, I feel like this could be abstracted away into `.map_if_ok(|thing| ...)`.

Is there another approach I can use to get this level of conciseness, or do I just need to tough it out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/dealing-with-result-within-iter ?

Comment: To reviewers: even if not a duplicate, this question is opinion-based and should remain closed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement these iterators yourself. See how [`filter`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/libcore/iter/mod.rs#L1552-L1560) and [`map`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/libcore/iter/mod.rs#L1307-L1310) are implemented in the standard library.

`map_ok` implementation:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MapOkIterator<I, F> {
    iter: I,
    f: F,
}

impl<A, B, E, I, F> Iterator for MapOkIterator<I, F>
where
    F: FnMut(A) -> B,
    I: Iterator<Item = Result<A, E>>,
{
    type Item = Result<B, E>;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next().map(|x| x.map(&mut self.f))
    }
}

pub trait MapOkTrait {
    fn map_ok<F, A, B, E>(self, func: F) -> MapOkIterator<Self, F>
    where
        Self: Sized + Iterator<Item = Result<A, E>>,
        F: FnMut(A) -> B,
    {
        MapOkIterator {
            iter: self,
            f: func,
        }
    }
}

impl<I, T, E> MapOkTrait for I
where
    I: Sized + Iterator<Item = Result<T, E>>,
{
}
```

`filter_ok` is almost the same:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct FilterOkIterator<I, P> {
    iter: I,
    predicate: P,
}

impl<I, P, A, E> Iterator for FilterOkIterator<I, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&A) -> bool,
    I: Iterator<Item = Result<A, E>>,
{
    type Item = Result<A, E>;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Result<A, E>> {
        for x in self.iter.by_ref() {
            match x {
                Ok(xx) => if (self.predicate)(&xx) {
                    return Some(Ok(xx));
                },
                Err(_) => return Some(x),
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

pub trait FilterOkTrait {
    fn filter_ok<P, A, E>(self, predicate: P) -> FilterOkIterator<Self, P>
    where
        Self: Sized + Iterator<Item = Result<A, E>>,
        P: FnMut(&A) -> bool,
    {
        FilterOkIterator {
            iter: self,
            predicate: predicate,
        }
    }
}

impl<I, T, E> FilterOkTrait for I
where
    I: Sized + Iterator<Item = Result<T, E>>,
{
}
```

Your code may look like this:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    .iter()
    .map(|x| x.parse::<u16>().map(|a| a + 10))
    .filter_ok(|x| x % 2 == 0)
    .map_ok(|x| x + 100)
    .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, std::num::ParseIntError>>()
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=316d31fca6bdbff00293f6a8c7919042&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: `vec![Ok(1),Ok(2),Err(3),Ok(4)].into_iter()....` looks better but creating a vector from the array is more expencive

Answer (score 104):

There are lots of ways you could mean this.

If you just want to panic, use `.map(|x| x.unwrap())`.

If you want all results *or* a single error, `collect` into a `Result<X<T>>`:

```
let results: Result<Vec<i32>, _> = result_i32_iter.collect();
```

If you want everything except the errors, use `.filter_map(|x| x.ok())` or `.flat_map(|x| x)`.

If you want everything *up to* the first error, use `.scan((), |_, x| x.ok())`.

```
let results: Vec<i32> = result_i32_iter.scan((), |_, x| x.ok());
```

Note that these operations can be combined with earlier operations in many cases.

Comment: An alternative to `scan` as used above would be `take_while(Result::is_ok).map(Result::unwrap)`

Comment: @goertzenator Best avoid panic-y code if there's an alternative, though.

Comment: I was buckling up to write a reducer that would return the first error result or the complete vector... but ```.collect()``` is amazing!

Answer (score 23):

Since Rust 1.27, [`Iterator::try_for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_for_each) could be of interest:

> An iterator method that applies a fallible function to each item in the iterator, stopping at the first error and returning that error.
>
> This can also be thought of as the fallible form of `for_each()` or as the stateless version of `try_fold()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) can be used to reduce simple cases of mapping then filtering. In your example there is some logic to the filter so I don't think it simplifies things. I don't see any useful functions in the documentation for `Result` either unfortunately. I think your example is as idiomatic as it could get, but here are some small improvements:

```
let things = vec![...]; // e.g. Vec<String>
things.iter().map(|thing| {
     // The ? operator can be used in place of try! in the nightly version of Rust
    let a = do_stuff(thing)?;
    Ok(other_stuff(a))
// The closure braces can be removed if the code is a single expression
}).filter(|thing_result| match *thing_result {
        Err(e) => true,
        Ok(a) => check(a),
    }
).map(|thing_result| {
    let a = thing_result?;
    // do stuff
    b
})
```

The `?` operator can be less readable in some cases, so you might not want to use it.

If you are able to change the `check` function to return `Some(x)` instead of true, and `None` instead of false, you can use `filter_map`:

```
let bar = things.iter().filter_map(|thing| {
    match do_stuff(thing) {
        Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        Ok(a) => {
            let x = other_stuff(a);
            if check_2(x) {
                Some(Ok(x))
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}).map(|thing_result| {
    let a = try!(thing_result);
    // do stuff
    b
}).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>();
```

You can get rid of the `let a = try!(thing);` by using a match in some cases as well. However, using `filter_map` here doesn't seem to help.