# Is there a way to remove unwrapping of items in an iterator chain that filters and partitions based on a Result?

Tags: iterator, rust

I created this example code:

```
fn main() {
    let books = vec![
        Book {
            data: Ok("type1".to_owned()),
            metadata: "meta1".to_owned(),
        },
        Book {
            data: Err("-".to_owned()),
            metadata: "meta2".to_owned(),
        },
        Book {
            data: Ok("type2".to_owned()),
            metadata: "meta2".to_owned(),
        },
    ];

    // metadata without data being error
    let (book_type_1, book_type_2): &(Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = &books
        .iter()
        .filter(|f| f.data.is_ok())
        .partition(|p| p.data.as_ref().unwrap() == "type1");

    println!("Books {:?}", books);
    println!("Type 1 {:?}", book_type_1); // Should be the original Vec<Book> with Type 1 filtered.
    println!("Type 2 {:?}", book_type_2); // Should be the original Vec<Book> with Type 2 filtered.
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Book {
    data: Result<String, String>,
    metadata: String,
}
```

On the `let (book_type_1, book_type_2)` expression, I need to use `Book::data` twice, but I already filtered it so I know it can't be `Err`. Is there a way to restructure to remove the use of `unwrap` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but it seems like you want to use [`Iterator::filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map). It lets you filter for values that are `Some(T)`, which then get passed on as unwrapped `T`s.

So what you can do is convert your `Result`s to `Option`s with [`Result::ok()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok), so a `Result::Ok(T)` will become `Some(T)` which means it passes the filter as `T`.

```
fn main() {
    let books = vec![
        Book {
            data: Ok("type1".to_owned()),
            metadata: "meta1".to_owned(),
        },
        Book {
            data: Err("-".to_owned()),
            metadata: "meta2".to_owned(),
        },
        Book {
            data: Ok("type2".to_owned()),
            metadata: "meta2".to_owned(),
        },
    ];

    // metadata without data being error
    let (book_type_1, book_type_2): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = books
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|f| {
            match &f.data {
                Ok(data) => Some((f, data)),
                Err(_) => None,
            }
        })
        .partition(|(book, data)| *data == "type1");

    println!("Books {:?}", books);
    println!("Type 1 {:?}", book_type_1);
    println!("Type 2 {:?}", book_type_2);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Book {
    data: Result<String, String>,
    metadata: String,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=26274a259559224b60747a1675491f56&version=stable&mode=debug)

I removed the unnecessary reference to the returned partitioned tuple.

Also note that `None` pertains to `Option<T>`, but you're using `Result<T, E>`. I think you knew that but just making sure.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. As for your example. The `metadata` is now missing, what I want is the whole `Book`. (I kept using `None` for `Err`, my mistake I will fix it)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. In that case you can't unwrap the `data` field in-place since the `data` field is specifically a `Result`. One thing you can do is unwrap it and store a copy or reference alongside `Book` in some wrapper type that would contain both values, such as a tuple. I'll write an example. Honestly, I get where you're coming from, but at that point it would be more work and more complexity than it's worth compared to just keeping the unwrap.

Comment: I had an example with `fold` working, where I just accumulate it as a tuple and discard the one where the `Result` is `Err`, but like you said it gets very long and compare to just `unwrap`.

Comment: Just in case anyone need to turn it back to just a Book. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=60ff77b80e9bc519c7856aaf71b5acad&version=stable&mode=debug)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `flat_map` as described [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50772500/155423), but I'd leave the yielded values as a `Result`. `Result` [implements `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-IntoIterator), so you can use it directly in `flat_map`.

I'd also use [`Result::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_ref) instead of writing out the match explicitly.

I'd then use [`Itertools::partition_map`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) to simultaneously select between the types and remove the extra property:

```
extern crate itertools;
use itertools::{Either, Itertools};

// ...

let (book_type_1, book_type_2): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = books
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|b| b.data.as_ref().map(|data| (b, data)))
    .partition_map(|(b, data)| {
        if data == "type1" {
            Either::Left(b)
        } else {
            Either::Right(b)
        }
    });
```

Note:

- There's no reason to take a reference to the result tuple.
- This only works because you are iterating on references to books.

If you needed to operate on the owned `Book`s, I'd move the comparison into the `flat_map` call and pass it along:

```
let (book_type_1, book_type_2): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = books
    .into_iter()
    .flat_map(|book| {
        book.data
            .as_ref()
            .ok()
            .map(|data| data == "type1")
            .map(|is_type1| (is_type1, book))
    })
    .partition_map(|(is_type1, book)| {
        if is_type1 {
            Either::Left(book)
        } else {
            Either::Right(book)
        }
    });
```

There's also the pragmatic solution of sorting all errors into the same bin as one of the types. Since you know that there *won't* be any errors, this has no effect:

```
let (book_type_1, book_type_2): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = books
    .iter()
    .filter(|f| f.data.is_ok())
    .partition(|p| p.data.as_ref().ok().map_or(false, |d| d == "type1"));
```

See also:

- [What's the most idiomatic way of working with an Iterator of Results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36368843/155423)