# How to wrap Result error in Some when using ? operator?

Tags: rust

I have a function, that returns `Option<Result<X, String>>` and it calls some functions that return `Result<Y, String>`. How is it possible to use the `?` operator in a way, that it wraps the error in a `Some`?

```rust
fn other_func() -> Result<Y, String> {
    // ...
}

fn my_func() -> Option<Result<X, String>> {
    // ...
    let value = other_func()?;
    // ...
}
```

I have two problems:

- I do not know how to wrap `?` in `Some`
- `Result<X, String>` is different from `Result<Y, String>`, but since I only care about the error at that point, it should not matter

I am able to solve it with combining match and return, but I would like to use `?` if it is possible somehow. This is my current solution:

```
let value = match other_func() {
    Ok(value) => value,
    Err(msg) => return Some(Err(msg))
};
```

Comment: `Option<Result<A, B>>` seems like an anti-pattern; it would make more sense to return `Result<Option<A>, B>`. That's assuming a `None` always means "completed successfully with no result". (If it means "failed with no error" (?) then `Result<A, Option<B>>` would be more appropriate, but then I wonder how it can ever make sense for something to fail with no error.)

Comment: If I implement an iterator for example it is always Optional<T> where T could be Result, not the other way around

Comment: I agree with kaya3. The two types are isomorphic but `Result<Option<A>, B>` makes more sense and works with `?`. If the caller of your function wants it the other way around, they can [`transpose`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.transpose) it on their side.

Comment: If you have an iterator over results, you probably do not want to continue after there is an error; but `Some(Err(...))` would signal that the iteration is not necessarily completed yet. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36368843/12299000) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26368288/12299000).

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible using the `?` operator, you would have to do what your current solution is.

Here is some info on what the `?` operator does: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/result/question_mark.html - it is just syntactic sugar around

```rust
match <expr> {
  Ok(val) => val,
  Err(err) => {
    return Err(From::from(err))
  }
}
```

so the only way to wrap your `Err` in `Some(err)` is by manually matching as you've done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function or closure that returns `Result<Option<X>, String>`, and then call `transpose()`. For example:

```
fn my_func() -> Option<Result<X, String>> {
    (|| -> Result<Option<X>, String> {
        // ...
        let _value = other_func()?;
        // ...
        Ok(None)
    })()
    .transpose()
}
```

If this use of closure is too obscure, you can simply define an inner `fn helper()` and call `helper().transpose()` (or define the helper outside `my_func`).