# Alternative to the try (?) operator suited to iterator mapping

Tags: error-handling, rust

In the process of learning Rust, I am getting acquainted with error propagation and the choice between `unwrap` and the `?` operator. After writing some prototype code that only uses `unwrap()`, I would like to remove `unwrap` from reusable parts, where panicking on every error is inappropriate.

How would one avoid the use of `unwrap` in a closure, like in this example?

```
// todo is VecDeque<PathBuf>
let dir = fs::read_dir(&filename).unwrap();
todo.extend(dir.map(|dirent| dirent.unwrap().path()));
```

The first `unwrap` can be easily changed to `?`, as long as the containing function returns `Result<(), io::Error>` or similar. However, the second `unwrap`, the one in `dirent.unwrap().path()`, cannot be changed to `dirent?.path()` because the closure must return a `PathBuf`, not a `Result<PathBuf, io::Error>`.

One option is to change `extend` to an explicit loop:

```
let dir = fs::read_dir(&filename)?;
for dirent in dir {
    todo.push_back(dirent?.path());
}
```

But that feels wrong - the original `extend` was elegant and clearly reflected the intention of the code. (It might also have been more efficient than a sequence of `push_back`s.) How would an experienced Rust developer express error checking in such code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would one avoid the use of `unwrap` in a closure, like in this example?

Well, it really depends on what you wish to do upon failure.

- should failure be reported to the user or be silent
- if reported, should *one* failure be reported or all?
- if a failure occur, should it interrupt processing?

For example, you could perfectly decide to silently ignore all failures and just skip the entries that fail. In this case, the [`Iterator::filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) combined with [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) is exactly what you are asking for.

```
let dir = fs::read_dir(&filename)?;
let todos.extend(dir.filter_map(Result::ok));
```

The `Iterator` interface is full of goodies, it's definitely worth perusing when looking for tidier code.

Comment: Good questions; I didn't want to go into specific usage examples to avoid making the question too long. Specifically, I would like to report all failures and continue processing. E.g. consider a function that counts files in subdirectories ([python](http://pastebin.com/XvzYZbsM)). The [rust version](http://pastebin.com/HFKHq54T) panics on every error, and I would like it to log the error on stderr and continue counting, like the Python one does.

Comment: @user4815162342: In this case you'll need pattern-matching in a `for` loop, and appending to a collection of `PathBuf` for the processing and another of `Error` for the issues.

Comment: You can use [`partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) to split the `Ok`s and the `Err`s into two collections, or [`partition_map`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.partition_map) from itertools if you want to remove the `Result` layer from both collections.

Comment: @FrancisGagné: It does not mesh with the Op's `todos.extend` though, as it creates a new collection rather than extending an existing one. `partition_map` looks pretty neat (but suffers from the same issue).

Comment: And if someone wants to stop on the first failure, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/how-do-i-stop-iteration-and-return-an-error-when-iteratormap-returns-a-result

Comment: @ArtemGr Looks very useful and concise to boot, thanks! After getting used to exceptions in Python and C++, it's takes time to learn the rust way of propagating error state, and such tools are indispensable.

Comment: I've posted a separate response based on combining `filter_map` with `Result::map_err` and `Result::ok` to ensure each error is logged rather than silently ignored. I'm not sure how idiomatic the new code is, but it feels significantly more elegant than previous attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `filter_map` suggested by [Matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m). It calls `Result::map_err` to ensure the error is "caught" and logged, sending it further to `Result::ok` and `filter_map` to remove it from iteration:

```
fn log_error(e: io::Error) {
    eprintln!("{}", e);
}

(|| {
    let dir = fs::read_dir(&filename)?;
    todo.extend(dir
                .filter_map(|res| res.map_err(log_error).ok()))
                .map(|dirent| dirent.path()));
})().unwrap_or_else(log_error)
```