# How to unzip a sequence of Result<(A, B), E> to a (Vec<A>, Vec<B>) and stop on first error?

Tags: iterator, rust

I would like to do something like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Foo(Vec<Stuff>),
    // ...
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn do_sth(&self) -> Result<Bar, E> {
        match *self {
            MyEnum::Foo(ref vec) => {
                let (a, b): (Vec<A>, Vec<B>) = vec
                    .iter()
                    .map(|thing| thing.make_a_tuple(arg)) // returns Result<(A, B), E>
                    .collect::<Result<_, _>>()? // stop on first error
                    .unzip();

                // use a and b
            }

            // other cases
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with `error: the type of this value must be known in this context`.
Through trial and error, I got it to compile like this

```
    fn do_sth(&self) -> Result<Bar, E> {
        match *self {
            MyEnum::Foo(ref vec) => {
                let (a, b): (Vec<A>, Vec<B>) = vec
                    .iter()
                    .map(|thing| thing.make_a_tuple(arg))
                    .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
                    .into_iter()
                    .unzip();

                // use a and b
            }

            // other cases
        }
    }
```

However, I would like to avoid the unnecessary allocation of a `Vec<(A, B)>`.

Is it possible to do this without intermediate allocations? I am sure I could do this myself with a loop, but I would prefer to learn the Rusty way.

Comment: "I don't fully understand why collect does the right thing when collecting a `Vec<Result<_, _>>`" That would make a separate question, which fortunately has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370894/1233251).

Comment: As for this matter, you have indeed stumbled upon an intriguing challenge. `unzip` behaves pretty much _unlike_ `collect`: explicitly according to the API, unzip will create two empty containers and shove data into them with `extend`. This means that it cannot do special tricks with `Result`

Comment: This is indeed helpful, thank you. But can I  collect into something like Result<SomeIterator, E>? Would this even make sense? Edit: Your second comment arrived on my screen just as I was posting my reply. I think I'll just keep things simple with a hand written loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've run into this type of problem with an iterator of `Result`s so commonly that I added a (private) helper type to the standard library called [`ResultShunt`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/libcore/iter/traits.rs#L738-L795). This powers the implementation of [`Sum` and `Product` for `Result`s](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.18.0/src/libcore/iter/traits.rs#L797-L817).

I also [submitted it to itertools](https://github.com/bluss/rust-itertools/pull/203) so it can be reused:

```rust
use itertools; // 0.10.1

fn main() {
    let iter_source: Vec<Result<(i32, i32), bool>> = vec![Ok((1, 2)), Err(false), Ok((3, 4))];

    let z = itertools::process_results(iter_source, |iter| iter.unzip::<_, _, Vec<_>, Vec<_>>());

    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! Also thanks for pointing me to itertools. I didn't even know about that crate.