# Using ? inside closure

Tags: rust

I've got this simple parsing function

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn parse_kv(data: &str) -> BTreeMap<String, String> {
    data.split('&')
        .map(|kv| kv.split('='))
        .map(|mut kv| (kv.next().unwrap().into(), kv.next().unwrap().into()))
        .collect()
}

#[test]
fn parse_kv_test() {
    let result = parse_kv("test1=1&test2=2");
    assert_eq!(result["test1"], "1");
    assert_eq!(result["test2"], "2");
}
```

It works fine and all, but I want to have Option or Result return type like so:

```
fn parse_kv(data: &str) -> Option<BTreeMap<String, String>>
```

This implementation:

```
fn parse_kv(data: &str) -> Option<BTreeMap<String, String>> {
    Some(data.split('&')
        .map(|kv| kv.split('='))
        .map(|mut kv| (kv.next()?.into(), kv.next()?.into()))
        .collect())
}
```

Unfortunately gives the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
  --> src/ecb_cut_paste.rs:23:24
   |
23 |         .map(|mut kv| (kv.next()?.into(), kv.next()?.into()))
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `(_, _)`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `(_, _)`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

Is it somehow possible to use `?` operator inside closure to return `None` from such function? If not, how would I need to handle idiomatically such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop iteration and return an error when Iterator::map returns a Result::Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/how-do-i-stop-iteration-and-return-an-error-when-iteratormap-returns-a-result)

Comment: Not really, because I'm chaining other functions after the `?` operator.

Comment: I don't agree it is a duplicate (though definitely related).  For one thing, the `?` operator didn't exist when that other question was posted and answered.  Plus, from a fairly quick look I'm struggling to see how to apply the ideas from the other question to this one easily.  I think the community could benefit from having this question answered anew.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that the closure itself is a function, so using `?` will return from the closure instead of the outer function. This can still be used to implement the function the way you want, however:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn parse_kv(data: &str) -> Option<BTreeMap<String, String>> {
    data.split('&')
        .map(|kv| kv.split('='))
        .map(|mut kv| Some((kv.next()?.into(), kv.next()?.into())))
        .collect()
}

#[test]
fn parse_kv_test() {
    let result = parse_kv("test1=1&test2=2").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(result["test1"], "1");
    assert_eq!(result["test2"], "2");

    let result2 = parse_kv("test1=1&test2");
    assert_eq!(result2, None);
}
```

There are a couple points to note here: First, the question marks and `Some(...)` in the second `map` invocation mean you have an iterator of `Option<(String, String)>` - type inference figures this out for you.

The next point of note is that `collect()` can automatically convert `Iterator<Option<T>>` into `Option<Collection<T>>` (same with `Result` - [relevant documentation here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect)). I added a test demonstrating that this works.

One other thing to be aware of is that using `collect` in this way still allows short-circuiting. Once the first `None` is yielded by the iterator, `collect` will immediately return with `None`, rather than continuing to process each element.

Comment: Great, that's the beauty I knew somehow existed but couldn't really figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Glad to help!

Comment: How would you do this if you're using `for_each` instead of `map` and therefore aren't collecting the results?

Comment: In that case I'd use a regular for loop, since they work with any iterator