# How can I replace `.unwrap()` with `?` when mapping over an `ndarray::Array`?

Tags: rust

I'd like to remove the use of `.unwrap()` from code which maps over an `ndarray::Array` and use a `Result` type for `get_data()` instead.

```rust
extern crate ndarray;

use ndarray::prelude::*;
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::error::Error;

fn get_data() -> Array2<usize> {
    // In actual code, "a" comes from an external source, and the type
    // is predetermined
    let a: Array2<i32> = arr2(&[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
    let b: Array2<usize> = a.map(|x| usize::try_from(*x).unwrap());
    b
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let a = get_data();
    println!("{:?}", a);

    Ok(())
}
```

For `Vec`, I've found this trick: [How do I stop iteration and return an error when Iterator::map returns a Result::Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/how-do-i-stop-iteration-and-return-an-error-when-iteratormap-returns-a-result).

However, this does not work with `Array`s (`collect` isn't defined, and the semantics don't quite match up, since `ndarray::Array` defines a block of primitive types, which (AFAIU) can't hold `Result`s).

Is there a nice way to handle this?

Comment: look like it's almost impossible to do, I advice you to create a issue asking for `try_map()` implementation

Comment: The closest thing I come up to is https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=413ae1a6e8e05fc93ee9cbba1b294704

Comment: A `try_map` implementation is the way to go. Short of that, I came up with: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d13538a717bd4bee9890961f6f9d5c27

Comment: @Stargateur thanks for the input.  I'll open an issue in `ndarray` about adding `.try_map`

Comment: @edwardw, thank you!  For now, I'll probably go with your solution (and open an issue regarding `try_map`).  Do you want to type it up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native `try_map` implementation from `ndarray` would be ideal. It can short-circuit the computation and return as soon as an error occurs. It is also more composable.

Short of that, nothing wrong with a good old mutable sentinel variable:

```rust
extern crate ndarray;

use ndarray::prelude::*;
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::error::Error;
use std::num::TryFromIntError;

fn get_data() -> Result<Array2<usize>, TryFromIntError> {
    let mut err = None;
    let a: Array2<i32> = arr2(&[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]);
    let b: Array2<usize> = a.map(|&x| {
        usize::try_from(x).unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            err = Some(e);
            Default::default()
        })
    });

    err.map_or(Ok(b), Err)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let a = get_data()?;
    println!("{:?}", a);

    Ok(())
}
```