# How to get Result's Ok value if the Result is in a Vector?

Tags: rust

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S{}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct E{}

fn test() -> Result<S, E> {
    let data_1: Result<S, E> = Ok(S{});
    let data_2: Result<S, E> = Err(E{});
    let v: Vec<Result<S, E>> = vec![data_1, data_2];

    for i in 1..2 {
        for item in &v {
            let val = item?; //error
            println!("{:?}", val);
        };
    }

    Ok(S{})
}
```

In the above code, I'd like to print the value of the item if the Result is Ok (otherwise return Err). But there is an error in `(*item)?` part due to moving a value behind shared reference:

> [rustc E0507] [E] cannot move out of `*item` which is behind a shared reference move occurs because `*item` has type `std::result::Result<tests::S, tests::E>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

I have tried cloning the data, but it doesn't solve the problem. Besides, it doesn't sound correct to clone.

What is the correct workaround/best practice for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop iteration and return an error when Iterator::map returns a Result::Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/how-do-i-stop-iteration-and-return-an-error-when-iteratormap-returns-a-result)

Comment: I think it could be a workaround. Out of curiosity, how if we would like to do it without relying on iterator? (i.e. still use for loop)

Comment: Is simply removing the reference (`for item in v`) a solution for you? If not, can you explain what you want to return? You can't return a reference to a value created inside a function.

Comment: For loops still use iterators internally. That is traversing an iterator where `Item = &Result<S, E>`. IIRC you can turn this into a `Result<&S, &E>` with a method (`as_ref`). How about just pattern matching over each item? `if let Ok(val) = item { ... }`

Comment: @trentcl it does in this case, but it doesn't in my real case (original question updated). I can't do `for item in v` because that looping is actually nested inside another loop. Hence, doing so would result in `use of moved value: "v". value moved here, in previous iteration of loop` error

Comment: I want to return a value derived from the Ok data

Comment: If in your real use case you have a function that takes `v` by reference and that's why you can't iterate over it by value, you could have it return `Result<S, &E>` (where the `S` is created inside the function and the `&E` a reference to the argument). If `v` is created inside the function but you want to iterate over it multiple times, I don't know if it makes sense to avoid cloning the `E`.

Comment: Maybe what you want is to pre-process the `Vec<Result<S, E>>` and return `Err` if any of them are `Err`, and then proceed to the rest of your algorithm with a `Vec<S>`? That sounds reasonable (although it calls into question why you have a `Vec` of `Result`s in the first place).

Comment: `match item { Ok(val) => println!("{:?}", val), Err(err) => return Err(err) }`

I tried exactly as you two described, yes the return would be `Result<S, &E>` (which doesn't match the signature (`Result<S, E>`)

Newbie question, how to convert `&E` to `E`? `return Err(err.clone())` doesn't work, the type is still `&E`

Comment: [Here's what I wrote that works.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=facb5ded7dd37876a012a4786aad226a) (Basically just a rehash of Aloso's answer)

Comment: I see, for the sake of other answer-seekers reading this: `struct E` needs to `#[derive(Clone)]`. Thx all, I learned a lot from this discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to format references (e.g. `&S`). However the `?` operator needs to return the error in the Result, so you must either copy, clone or move it:

## Copy

If you implement the `Copy` trait for your types, you can dereference `&Result<S, E>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4cc656610f48c1a14dd0e27ec17be333)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct S {}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct E {}
```

You can also make it work if the error type implements `Copy`, but not the ok type ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc05dad3609d254efb9a0815afbe0ba5)).

## Clone

You have to clone types, if you need to convert a reference to an owned type that isn't `Copy`. Example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fccebd2082a3a3a48f4a1e3db234e4cb)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct S {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct E {}

let val = item.clone()?;
```

You can change this to only clone in case of an error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=265ce1be5c2a6c74293f0745e7b88dce)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct E {}

let val = item.as_ref().map_err(Clone::clone)?;
```

## Move

If you don't need the vector after iterating over it, you can move it:

```rust
for item in v {  // this calls `IntoIterator::into_iter(v)` implicitly
    let val = item?;
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

Or, you can convert the `Vec<Result<S, E>>` to a `Result<Vec<S>, E>` first:

```rust
// collects the `Ok` values, or returns the first error it encounters
let v: Vec<S> = v.into_iter().collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;

for item in &v {
    println!("{:?}", item);
}
```

Comment: @pahlevi-fikri-auliya thanks for accepting my answer! May I ask what method you used?

Comment: They all work in the simplified code I put here. Still trying in my real code, like the answer with Clone turns out requiring adding Clone in many other parts. I am curious about the last option, why does converting `Vec<Result<S, E>>` to `Result<Vec<S>, E>` help?

Comment: The last example works, because it doesn't return an error in the `for` loop with `?`. It only uses `?` on the `Result<Vec<S>, E>`, which is not behind a reference.