# How do you handle errors inside a Rust filter()?

Tags: filter, error-handling, rust, iterator

I'd like to use a filter function that may return an `Err` result, and bubble it up to the containing function:

```rust
mycoll.into_iter()
  .filter(|el| {
    if el == "bad" {
      Err(MyError)
    } else {
      Ok(el < "foo")
    }
  })
```

I found a good explanation on how to handle this type of case when it comes to `map()` (using `.collect::<Result<...>>()`): [How do I stop iteration and return an error when Iterator::map returns a Result::Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/how-do-i-stop-iteration-and-return-an-error-when-iteratormap-returns-a-result) but I can't get a similar solution to work for `filter()`.

What's the idiomatic solution here?

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably suggest using [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map). Your example would look like:

```rust
mycoll.into_iter()
  .filter_map(|el| {
    if el == "bad" {
      Some(Err(MyError))
    } else if el < "foo" {
      Some(Ok(el))
    } else {
      None
    }
  })
```