# What should be the callback type signature for itertools::process_results() in Rust?

Tags: types, rust, iterator

To parse a large file line-by-line I was trying to use [itertools::process_results](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/fn.process_results.html) in the following manner, having it fail immediately if the file cannot be read:

```
fn parse_file() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let reader = BufReader::new(File::open("file")?);
    let line_iter = process_results(reader.lines(), filter_lines);
    unimplemented!()
}

fn filter_lines<I: Iterator<Item=String>>(lines: I) -> impl Iterator<Item=String> {
    lines.filter(|line| {
        unimplemented!()
    })
}
```

However, the compiler is not happy with the signature of `filter_lines` and says something like

> error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
>
> expected signature of `for<'r> fn(itertools::process_results_impl::ProcessResults<'r,  std::io::Lines<std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>>, std::io::Error>) -> _`

Since `ProcessResults` implements `Iterator`, I don't understand the problem here.
How would the type of `filter_lines` need to be changed for it to work with `process_results`?

Comment: For ease of experimentation: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=314c407fbc6f261585900bf6957967c6)

Answer (score 1):

> Since `ProcessResults` implements `Iterator`, I don't understand the problem here.

The problem is not in the trait bounds, but in the lifetime of the value returned by `filter_lines`. `process_results` hands you an iterator that refers to data local to `process_results` invocation. You can use that iterator, such as by iterating over it or passing it to functions, but you're not allowed to *return* it out of the callback, nor to return an iterator that refers to it, as `filter_lines()` does. This is because the value returned from the callback is returned by `process_results` itself, and that value must not refer to data local to `process_results`.

For example, this implementation of `filter_lines()`, which goes through the iterator and returns a value based on the values found inside, compiles:

```
fn filter_lines<I: Iterator<Item = String>>(lines: I) -> Option<usize> {
    lines.map(|line| line.len()).max()
}
```

Likewise, leaving your implementation of `filter_lines`, but not returning the iterator from the callback, also compiles:

```
// with filter_lines as originally defined
let line_max = process_results(reader.lines(), |lines| filter_lines(lines).max());
```

If you want to build a new iterator that stops when an existing iterator encounters an error, you won't be able to use `process_results()`. Instead, you will need to use [`take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) or [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) with some outside state, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120052/1600898). Applied to your code, `scan` would be used like this:

```
fn parse_file() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let reader = BufReader::new(File::open("file")?);
    let mut err = Ok(());
    let line_iter = reader.lines().scan(&mut err, until_err);
    let new_iter = filter_lines(line_iter)
    // some processing, e.g.:
    new_iter.for_each(|line| todo!());
    err?;  // check whether iteration was ended by error Result
    unimplemented!()
}

// filter_lines as originally written...

// helper function for `Iterator::scan()`
fn until_err<T, E>(err: &mut &mut Result<(), E>, item: Result<T, E>) -> Option<T> {
    match item {
        Ok(item) => Some(item),
        Err(e) => {
            **err = Err(e);
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I still get a type error when not returning the iterator: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77c332718e8b20cea4e79bb18ea3b71d

Comment: @wonce Interesting, it works only with a closure in-between, as in my answer.

Comment: So the lifetime is actually a deeper, second problem. I assume the closure resolves the type error because it is inferred to have the correct type, which is mysteriously compatible yet incompatible with `filter_lines`.