# Is there any way to "early return" in a declarative macro iterations?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm new to Rust's macros.

I'd like to find a way to achieve a behaviour like this: [early return in iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370894)

I learned I can generate tuples using a declarative macro like this one:

```
fn function(input) -> Result<input_type,err_type> {
    // do something
}

macro_rules! to_tuple {
    ($($input:expr),*) => (($( function($input), )*));
}

fn main() {
    to_tuple!(i_1, i_2);
    // I will get a tuple: (o_1, o_2)
}
```

Now I'd like to check result of `function` in every iteration. If they are all ok, I'll get a `Ok(tuple)`. If error occurs, I'll get a `Err(stirng)`. Like:

```
to_tuple!(right_1, right_2) => Ok( (o_1, o_2) )
to_tuple!(right_1, right_2, right_3) => Ok( (o_1, o_2, o_3) )
to_tuple!(right_1, wrong_1, right_2) => Err( string )
```

Is this possible using declarative macros?

I think what macros produces is not real iterations, so there is no iterations, therefore apparently there is no "early return". I wish I were wrong. If anyone has any idea, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a perfect place for [`try` blocks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html). Except they're unstable. But we can emulate them with a closure:

```rust
macro_rules! to_tuple {
    ($($input:expr),*) => ((|| -> Result<_, String> { Ok(($( function($input)?, )*)) })());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly fine! I was busy last 2 days, sorry for the late response!

Comment: I'd like to know if I can find documents about how closures with question marks turn into try blocks

Comment: @cyvb Nothing official that I know, but there is also not much to know.