# Iterator's predicate returns Result<bool, E>, how do I stop iteration and return the error

Tags: rust, iterator

```
type E = String;

fn helper() -> Result<char, E> {
    let pred = |x| -> Result<bool, E> {
        if x % 3 {
            Ok(x % 2)
        } else {
            Err("error".to_string())
        }
    };
    let it = "abcde".chars().filter(pred);
    return it.next()
}
```

How do you solve this? Capture a mutable reference to an `Option<E>`?

Here's the solution to a similar problem but for `map` [How do I stop iteration and return an error when Iterator::map returns a Result::Err?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368288/how-do-i-stop-iteration-and-return-an-error-when-iteratormap-returns-a-result)

Comment: `pred()` expects an integer, but the iterator is of `char`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map):

```rust
let mut it = "abcde".chars().filter_map(|item| match pred(item) {
    Ok(should_return) => should_return.then_some(Ok(item)),
    Err(err) => Some(Err(err)),
});
return it.next();
```

Or [`find_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map) if all you want is `next()`:

```rust
"abcde".chars().find_map(|item| match pred(item) {
    Ok(should_return) => should_return.then_some(Ok(item)),
    Err(err) => Some(Err(err)),
})
```

Comment: What about `skip_while`? The best solution I think would be to create a new iterator, copy pasting the code from the rust standard library